# How does the Google ML Kit figure out someone is smiling?

Tags: face-detection, google-mlkit

I was looking at the official explanation of the plugin. However, it lacks explanation on how it recognizes one is smiling. I am guessing it is using the contour detection to figure this out. If so, can a custom parameter be calculated based on the focused attributes? For example, a laughing parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is likely wrong, given the fact that you can still use ML Kit to determine if someone is smiling without enabling the contour detection mode. ML Kit does not currently supporting calculating a custom parameter based on the focused attributes.